# How to use completion block with delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, objective-c-blocks

I have class A that's set as a delegate for class B. How it works currently is a method from class A uses an instance of class B to call a method. After B's method is done executing, it call a delegate method implemented in A.

What is want is have class A's method to include a success completion block, so that when it B's method is done executing, I could know from the same method in class A that B's method is successfully executed. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

In class A, store the block as a property. In class B's delegate method (implemented by class A), you can then call the block via the property.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^completion)(BOOL);

- (void)classAMethod:(void (^)(BOOL))completion {
    self.completion = completion;
    [classB method];
}

- (void)classBDelegateMethod:(BOOL)result {
    if(self.completion) {  
        self.completion(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll want to check that `completion` is non-`nil` before calling it in `-classBDelegateMethod`, otherwise the app will crash. You also may want to ensure you're not overriding an existing block in `-classAMethod:`,  otherwise blocks may not be invoked as expected. You may want to store an array of blocks.

Comment: Updated the answer. As for the array of completions, it depends on the nature of classAMethod. You may want to allow it to run multiple times in parallel, or have one execution going at a time. If it's the former, the array of completions makes sense.

Comment: @Mark I think this is what I'm looking for. How do I change it if I want a to pass a BOOL to my classBDelegateMethod so that classAMethod gets it?